# How to add leading zeros for id in SQL

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Customer Id has a problem of not being able to be sorted, this is because the customer id is designed with a letter in front, because of this the id C10, C11, C12, etc will appear before C2. To solve this problem, we decided to match the number of digits of the biggest id; for example if the biggest customer id is C182, this id has 3 digits which means that we will add 1 zero to ids with 2 digit and 2 zeros for ids with only 1 digit(ex:C81 will become C081, C7 will become C007).

Doing this will help sort the ids when needed. How do we solve this in SQL?

Comment: You "solve" this in SQL by not combining data that has two different discreet meanings; prefixing with the letter, which has its own meaning, is something for the presentation layer. Keeping the numerical part of the customer ID separate means you won't run into issues such as this.

Comment: If you want data to be sorted in numerical order, store it in a numerical data type. For your data, I would suggest that the number and prefix should be in different columns. Then, if needed, use a computed column for your concatenated value.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using 2 methods.

**Method 1**

Remove the 'C' from id and cast it to integer and use it in the order by clause.

```
select * from your_table
order by cast(replace(id, 'C', '') as int);
```

**Method 2**

If you need to sort based on the numbers in id column, then we can simply sort it by length of id column and then with id itself.

```
select * from your_table
order by len(id), id;
```

[Find demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/aff3c/1)